# mysql query running too slow for discontinuous data

Tags: mysql, sum, query-optimization, average

I am new to MySQL, and trying to using MySQL on the project, basically was tracking players performance.
Below is the table fields.

```
+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field             | Type                 | Collation         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| unique_id         | int(11)              | NULL              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| record_time       | datetime             | NULL              | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| game_sourceid     | char(20)             | latin1_swedish_ci | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| game_number       | smallint(6)          | NULL              | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| game_difficulty   | char(12)             | latin1_swedish_ci | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| cost_time         | smallint(5) unsigned | NULL              | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| country           | char(3)              | latin1_swedish_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| source            | char(7)              | latin1_swedish_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

and I have adding `game_sourceid` and `game_difficulty` as index and the engine is innodb.

I have insert about 11m rows of test data into this table, which is generated randomly but resembles the real data.

Basically the mostly query was like this, to get the average time and best time for a specific `game_sourceid`

```
SELECT avg(cost_time) AS avgtime
    , min(cost_time) AS mintime
    , count(*) AS count
FROM statistics_work_table
WHERE game_sourceid = 'standard_easy_1';

+-----------+---------+--------+
| avgtime   | mintime | count  |
+-----------+---------+--------+
| 1681.2851 |     420 | 138034 |
+-----------+---------+--------+
1 row in set (4.97 sec)
```

and the query took about 5s

I have googled about this and someone said that may caused by the amout of query count, so I am trying to narrow down the scope like this

```
SELECT avg(cost_time) AS avgtime
    , min(cost_time) AS mintime
    , count(*) AS count
FROM statistics_work_table
WHERE game_sourceid = 'standard_easy_1'
    AND record_time > '2015-11-19 04:40:00';

+-----------+---------+-------+
| avgtime   | mintime | count |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| 1275.2222 |     214 |     9 |
+-----------+---------+-------+

1 row in set (4.46 sec)
```

As you can see the 9 rows data also took about 5s, so i think it's not the problem about the query count.

The test data was generated randomly to simulate the real user's activity, so the data was discontinuous, so i added more continuous data(about 250k) with the *same* `game_sourceid='standard_easy_9'` but keep all others randomly, in other words the last 250k rows in this table has the same `game_sourceid`. And i'm trying to query like this:

```
SELECT avg(cost_time) AS avgtime
    , min(cost_time) AS mintime
    , count(*) AS count
FROM statistics_work_table
WHERE game_sourceid = 'standard_easy_9';

+-----------+---------+--------+
| avgtime   | mintime | count  |
+-----------+---------+--------+
| 1271.4806 |      70 | 259379 |
+-----------+---------+--------+
1 row in set (0.40 sec)
```

This time the query magically took only 0.4s, that's totally beyond my expectations.

So here's the question, the data was retrived from the player at real time, so it must be randomly and discontinuous.

I am thinking of separating the data into multiple tables by the game_sourceid, but it will take another 80 tables for that, maybe more in the future.

Since I am new to MySQL, I am wondering if there are any other solutions for this, or just my query was too bad.

> Update: Here's the index of my table

```
mysql> show index from statistics_work_table;

+-----------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                 | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| statistics_work_table |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | unique_id       | A         |    11362113 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| statistics_work_table |          1 | GameSourceId_CostTime   |            1 | game_sourceid   | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| statistics_work_table |          1 | GameSourceId_CostTime   |            2 | cost_time       | A         |      344306 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Please consider formatting your question. It'll be difficult for anyone to answer the way it is now.

Comment: yes, it's the first time i'm post in stackoverflow, and trying to formatting the questions but just can't get it done, it make's me head ache. AH!

Comment: I guess you got the help you needed!

Comment: @justcurious what do you mean? seperate into mutiple tables by the game_sourceid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `statistics_work_table`
ADD INDEX `GameSourceId_CostTime` (`game_sourceid`,`cost_time`)
```

This index should make your queries super fast. Also, after you run the above statement, you should drop the single column index you have on `game_sourceid`, as the above will make the single column one redundant. (Which will hurt insert speed.)

The reason your queries are slow is because the database is using your single column index on `game_sourceid`, finding the rows, and then, for each row, using the primary key that is stored along with the index to find the main clustered index (aka primary key in this, and most cases), and then looking up the `cost_time` value. This is referred to as a double lookup, and it is something you want to avoid.

The index I provided above is called a "covering index". It allows your query to use ONLY the index, and so you only need a single lookup per row, greatly improving performance.

Comment: @Tommy, this answer will give you a great start.  In addition, if you are querying based on a given time period, such as for a game on or after a given date/time, adding your "record_time" to the covering index would benefit.  So this one index would be ( game_sourceid, record_time, cost_time ).

Comment: @Willem Renzema I've done what you said but unfortunately the query still take about 5s, i've updated the question with index of my table. am i missing something?

Comment: my bad, i'm running the query for wrong table, the query now running super fast (0.1s),  and @DRapp Thank you guys so much.

Comment: @tommy If my answer solved your issue, please accept it.